# syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon, don't know why?

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

why do I get the error: syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon on line 7???

```
var myXML:XML=new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.onLoad = function(succes:Boolean):void{
    var colors:XML = this.firstChild;
    for (x=0;x<colors.childNodes.length;x++){
        var node:XMLNode = colors.childNodes[x];
        colors_cb.addItem{(label:node.attributes.label,data:node.attributes.data)};

    }
}
myXML.load("colors.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you inverted { and ( in your function call addItem 
try:

```
colors_cb.addItem({label:node.attributes.label,data:node.attributes.data});
```

it seems you are using ActionScript2 methods for XML class. Try this:

```
// create a loader for your XML
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
// Lister for complete event
xmlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onLoadComplete );
// start loading
xmlLoader.load( 'colors.xml' );

// handle complete loading
function _onLoadComplete( e:Event ):void
{
    // remove event listener
    xmlLoader.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, _onLoadComplete );
    // set XML to ignore white spaces
    XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
    // create XML with the loaded data
    var colors:XML = new XML( e.target.data );

    // add your items to your color_cb
    for (var x:int=0; x<colors.childNodes.length; x++ )
    {
        var node:XMLNode = colors.childNodes[x];
        color_cb.addItem({label:node.attributes.label,data:node.attributes.data});
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks This: <colors>
 <color label="Red" data="1" />
 <color label="Green" data="2" />
 <color label="Blue" data="3" />
</colors> is my xml file but it doesn't work do you know why?

Comment: I get this errors: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 3 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onLoad event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'load', callback_handler). and:Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 11 Warning: 3594: load is not a recognized method of the dynamic class XML.